# Do the Keystore / json files the same across different wallets?

Tags: wallets

So I downloaded a version of MyEtherWallet.com onto my computer and generated a new wallet. It gave me a keystore which when decrypted contains my private and public keys.

I plan to buy some ethereum and have it for many years without touching it.

When I do want to access it, who knows whether MyEtherWallet.com will still exist.

So my question is, is this keystore file in some sort of common format that all ethereum wallets will understand or would I need to use MyEtherWallet to unencrypt it?

If so, I was thinking might be a good idea to put a version of the MyEtherWallet site on the USB drives where I will keep my keystore file.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* a fairly standard format, used by Geth and documented there. MEW supports it, the keythereum Node library supports it, Parity supports it, and probably others.

That said, it's a great idea to download MEW and keep your own copy of it, so I would still recommend doing that.